Safari : is the behaviour of overflow hidden and drop-shadow as it should be?
You have to have access to a Safari, from iOS (using a tap to see the hover effect) or macOS. I have the latests versions of iOS and macOS.
I have a div with an img, and some text. I want to make a drop-shadow appear on hover, and I want the image to scale, while preserving its size. I also want the whole div to have rounded corners.
here is a recreation of what I describe :


.has-over-effect {
  width: 200px;
  transition-property: filter;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0 white);
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.has-over-effect:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px black); 
}

.has-over-effect img {
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.has-over-effect p {
  padding: 1em;
}

.has-over-effect:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="has-over-effect">
<div class="overflow-hidden">
<img src="https://placehold.co/200x200" />
</div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Curae primis velit conubia class primis volutpat. Vitae orci facilisi suscipit maecenas gravida nibh sagittis.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>



It works as intended on chrome and firefox, but in safari, the animation takes place, and when it ends, the drop-shadow disappears, and then when you hover out, it suddenly reappears, and animates to the original state.
I identified the cause : the whole div has an overflow: hidden, to make the image have rounded corners. If I remove that, it works as intended, but judging from chrome and firefox, overflow: hidden shouldn't have an impact on drop-shadow. Also notable is that you can see the animation in and out, but not its final state while hovering.
